# How can I test a class with @invocableMethod and SchedulableContext

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I'm not getting coverage for this class, as it would be to test @invocableMethod

```
    global class CallFraudPreventionEventLogs implements Schedulable { 

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) { 
        GenerateFraudPreventionEventLogView gfp = new GenerateFraudPreventionEventLogView(); 
        gfp.executeLog(); 
    }

    @invocableMethod
    public static void executeCallFraudPreventionEventLog() {         
        GenerateFraudPreventionEventLogView gfp = new GenerateFraudPreventionEventLogView(); 
        gfp.executeLog(); 
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class CallFraudPreventionEventLogsTest {
    static TestMethod void TestOne(){      
        Test.startTest();     
        new CallFraudPreventionEventLogs().execute(null);               
        Test.stopTest(); 
    }
    
    public static TestMethod void testTwo() {
    Test.startTest(); 
        CallFraudPreventionEventLogs.executeCallFraudPreventionEventLog();
    Test.stopTest(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: As with any Apex test, you simply have to invoke the code (call the static method) and validate the results.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for the support, friend, hugs!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! It's considered bad form to edit the question to include the answer (see [ask], [answer] and [Can I answer my own question?](/help/self-answer)). Please consider reverting your question and adding the code as an answer. Simply putting "Solved" in the title does not "solve" the question. After adding your own answer, you can ✔ your answer to let others know it was the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox A thousand pardons, I will correct!

Comment: The answer section is lower, this is just a comment area. There's a blue button down lower that should read "Answer your own question" or something to that effect. Just copy-paste your code and a brief summary of the solution in that box, and you'll be good. I could do it for you, but I don't want to take your rep away from you, so I'd rather you do it yourself.

Comment: @sfdcfox Sorry for my failure, is that I am already awake days to complete this project, but now I finally managed to complete it, thank you for the guidance, as I am new to the site. Hugs!

Answer (score 2):

Passing the parameter as null is possible to complete the test successfully, and for @InvocableMethod it is only to perform the normal test.

```
@isTest
public class CallFraudPreventionEventLogsTest {
    static TestMethod void TestOne(){      
        Test.startTest();     
        new CallFraudPreventionEventLogs().execute(null);               
        Test.stopTest(); 
    }
    
    public static TestMethod void testTwo() {
    Test.startTest(); 
        CallFraudPreventionEventLogs.executeCallFraudPreventionEventLog();
    Test.stopTest(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: There you go! I cleaned it up for you as an example for you to use in the future. I hope that you enjoy your experience here and come back as often as you need!